# Show that the elements {$e,a,a^{2},...,a^{n-1}$} are all distinct

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups

**Problem Statement**

Let $a$ be an element of a group such that $a^{k} = e$ for some $k > 0$ Let $n$ be the least positive integer such that $a^{n} = e$. Show that the elements $e,a,a^{2},...,a^{n-1}$ are all distinct.

Note: We cannot use propositions related to establishing an isomorphism between a finite cyclic group of order $n$ and $\mathbb{Z_n}$ nor the statement that if the order of $a$ is finite and $n$ then $\langle a \rangle = $ {$a^{k}: 0 \leq k < o(a)$}

---

**Attempt at a solution**

Let's assume the elements of {$e,a,...,a^{n-1}$} are not all distinct and that 2 elements, $a^{l}$ and $a^{m}$ such that $0 < l,m \leq (n-1)$, coincide. So that: $a^{l} = a^{m}$.

Now, $a^{l}a^{-l} = a^{l-l} = a^{0} = e = a^{m-l} = a^{m}a^{-l}$. Thus, we see that if $2$ elements coincide, they must have the same power. So, no $2$ elements of different powers can coincide and hence all elements are distinct.

---

I'm just looking for clarification that this is a valid solution to the problem and that there aren't any holes in my logic. Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: If $0\le j<k\le n-1$ and $a^j=a^k$ then $0<k-j<n$ but $a^{k-j}=e, $ contrary to the minimality of $n.$

Comment: You want $m-l$ to be a positive integer less than $n$ for $a^{m-l} = e$ to give a contradiction so order $l$ and $m$.

Comment: Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.